# Creating function just to return date

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, date, datetime

The function should take a list of strings as input. Each string in the input list is formatted as 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss'.
The function should return a list of strings where each element in the returned list contains only the date in the 'yyyy-mm-dd' format.

```
def date_parser(dates):
    """

    This function takes as input a list of these datetime strings and returns only the date in 'yyyy-mm-dd' format.

    Parameters:
    -----------
    items: (list), list of datetime strings.

    Returns:
    --------
    returns a list of strings where each element in the returned list contains only the date in the 'yyyy-mm-dd' format.

    """
    my_list = []

    for date in dates:
        my_list.append(date)

        my_list[:10]

    return my_list

### START FUNCTION
def date_parser(dates):
    """

    This function takes as input a list of these datetime strings and returns only the date in 'yyyy-mm-dd' format.

    Parameters:
    -----------
    items: (list), list of datetime strings.

    Returns:
    --------
    returns a list of strings where each element in the returned list contains only the date in the 'yyyy-mm-dd' format.

    """
    my_list = []

    for date in dates:
        my_list.append(date)

        my_list[:10]

    return my_list
```

Comment: what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: I need to write a function that will only return the dates, not the datetime. The values given are '2019-11-29 12:50:54', '2019-11-29 12:46:53', '2019-11-29 12:46:10'

Answer (score 0):

**If you can assure that the input list contains only valid dates** you can simply do something like this:

```
my_list = []

    for date in dates:
        my_list.append(date[:10])
    return my_list
```

or use [list comprehension](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python) (which I think looks better)

```
return [datetime_string[:10] for datetime_string in dates]
```